# Git Push Hangs After a Few Pushes

Tags: git, ssh, github

I start up Ubuntu Linux, open a terminal, edit some code, and happily execute

```
git push origin master
```

However, after some period of time (sometimes 30 mins, sometimes a few hours), the exact same command will hang (no output at all).

When I try

```
ssh -v git@github.com
```

I get the following response:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/avitus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
```

And then it hangs again. It seems as though I can no longer use SSH to git once I've SSH'ed to another server. Any ideas how to fix this? It is killing me having to reboot each time.

Update:

The problem goes away when I remove the following two lines (intended to facilitate connection sharing) from ~/.ssh/config

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
```

Comment: Have you at any point set up another SSH connection to GitHub as control master?  (That's a mechanism for sharing an existing connection.)  That debug message looks as it has found an existing SSH control master

Comment: Mark - I think the problem is something like what you're mentioned because when I removed the two lines above everything started working again. I only have one user connecting to Git on this machine, though.

Comment: great, I'm glad to hear you got that working.  I've added an answer along those lines now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Just turning my guess from a comment into an answer...*

The last line in the output of `ssh -v`:

```
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
```

... tells you that SSH has been configured to look for an existing SSH connection to reuse.  I suspect that this existing connection eventually gets stuck in some way, which would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

This connection sharing facility is described in the `ControlMaster` section of [the `ssh_config(5)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).  Essentially the "master" SSH session creates a socket in `/tmp` which later sessions can connect to instead of having to go through the potentially length authentication step again.  You have this option set to `auto`, which means that this socket will be created and used automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while before stumbling onto a help page buried under GitHub support:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Turns out my workplace had just the right magic combination of firewall/port protection to "almost" allow regular Git SSH access to GitHub, i.e. it worked "occasionally" but not reliably. ;-b

With this incantation in my $HOME/.ssh/config file, to use SSH Over HTTPS, I was suddenly able to access my GitHub repo from the command line via my SSH Key in GitHub:

```
Host github.com

User git

Hostname ssh.github.com

Port 443 

PreferredAuthentications publickey

IdentityFile /home/XXX/.ssh/github_id_rsa

TCPKeepAlive yes     # not sure if truly needed

IdentitiesOnly yes   # not sure if truly needed
```

Enjoy!
Jeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeem :)